# Kill unresponsive process by name but preserve responsive processes

Tags: process, osx, kill

For some reason, I end up with a fair few Google Chrome Helper processes which stop responding, hogging CPU resources. Usually I just run `killall Google\ Chrome\ Helper`, however this kills all, including the responsive processes meaning that I have to restart Chrome.

Is there a flag for `killall` so it only affects unresponsive processes?

Comment: How will you identify "unresponsiveness"?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/LfBqIlfFoSo[1-25-false]) issue had been going for a long time.

Comment: If you open up Activity Monitor on Mac, you'll see unresponsive processes in red with `(Not Responding)` appended to the name.

Comment: Related answer to fully automate killing of misbehaving firefox/chrome browser tabs:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484388/monitoring-cpu-of-tabs-in-firefox/729712#729712

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use `top` to find the pid of the process using the most CPU.  I started a bash CPU hog in one terminal:

```
bash -c "while true; do :; done"
```

Then in another terminal I can kill it as follows:

```
kill $( top -l2 | grep bash | sort -nrk3 | awk '{print $1;exit}' )
```

Note, since this is [osx](/questions/tagged/osx), this is the BSD `top` and not the GNU version.

- `-l2` tells top to run for 2 iterations - the first needs to be ignored as it just reports 0% CPU for all processes.
- The `grep` filters just the bash lines.  Note this may need more work if your grep expression matches any other parts of the `top` output.
- `sort` sorts the output numerically in reverse by the 3rd column (CPU %)
- `head` gets the first line (highest CPU)
- `cut` gets the first column (PID)
- The above is executed in a `$()` command substitution, and the numerical PID is just passed directly to `kill`

---

On GNU/Linux machines the equivalent is:

```
kill $(top -bn1 | grep bash | sort -nrk9 | awk '{print $1;exit}')
```