# Monitoring CPU% of Tabs in Firefox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, firefox

Sometimes, when I have numerous tabs open in Firefox, one of those tabs will start consuming a lot of CPU%, and I want to know which tab is the culprit. Doing this is a very manual process for which I'd like to find automation.

I wish I had an application that could monitor firefox exclusively in a manner that produces concise output of only the firefox-facts I want to know.

I'm looking for a command/application that will list the processes of each tab running in firefox filtered to only include the following info for each tab-process:

1. Process ID
2. Webpage Address of Tab
3. CPU % usage
4. Memory used

Additionally, I'd like the info sorted by CPU % descending.

Basically, I hoping there exists a program like htop, but that's exclusively dedicated to just the pertinent stuff I want to monitor in Firefox (while leaving out all the details I don't care about).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can type `about:performance` in the address bar of firefox. Then you will get a table where there will be `pid` of each tab of firefox with `Resident Set size` and `Unique Set Size`. And below this there will be some lines explaining the performance of each tab (like `performing well`) and if a tab is not performing well then it will show there and you can close that tab from there using the `Close Tab` option.

Comment: `about:performance` gets a total redesign with more and better information [from FF65](https://techdows.com/2018/11/mozilla-makes-about-performance-as-complete-task-manager-in-firefox-65.html).

Comment: Suggestion: This answer might want to explain the recent changes made to `about:performance` before and after Firefox 65. There is no more table with "pid" or "set size".

Answer (score 2):

You may want to go one step further, and automate the process:

- Auto-detect processes (which can be running in browser tabs) which are hogging your CPU
- Terminate them if/once they exceed certain/unreasonable thresholds

Here's a generic/customizable script I wrote, called
[***cpu-hog-killer***](https://github.com/arielf/scripts/blob/master/cpu-hog-killer) to address this issue of malicious or otherwise misbehaving scripts in  browsers (or elsewhere).

The script defines two basic primitives:

- `process-list`: pick processes based on a command+args regex
- `terminate-hogs`: kill processes exceeding desired CPU (total-seconds & current %pct) consumption

and uses them to achieve this goal.

Here's the description, as taken from the README.md in the git repo.

#### cpu-hog-killer

Kill high-CPU hogging processes by command+args regex & CPU consumption.

Buggy (or malicious) 3rd-party javascript code is often taking
our browsers and computing resources hostage.

I used to find some processes on my desktop running at 100% CPU
all night when I was not even noticing, because of bad javascript.

Involuntary CPU hogging might be caused by an infected ad,
badly written code, "drive-by-scripting" leading to someone
co-opting your computer to run crypto-mining, or much worse.

It makes you pay for electricity you don't want to, and multiplied
by many desktops and browsers left running at night, is also very bad
for our planet.

`cpu-hog-killer` is a simple script which I run from periodically
during the night.  I make it run from cron every 13 minutes like this:

```
    # Add this line (or similar) using 'crontab -e'
    */13 0-7 * * *  ~/bin/cpu-hog-killer
```

It identifies *certain* CPU hogging processes, mainly inside Chrome or Firefox, and kills them instantly upon detection.
Note that it doesn't kill processes taking CPU indiscriminately, nor
it kills the main browser process.
It only kills those processes that you explicitly say you want
terminated based on configured `regex` + `CPU consumption parameters`.

In the morning when I'm back, the worst case scenario is that
I go to a browser tab and it says (e.g. for Firefox):

```
    "Gah. Your tab just crashed."
```

I take notice of which site was misbehaving (based on its title)
and the browser allows me (presenting a big button) to:

```
    [Restore This Tab]
```

if I want to, so nothing is actually lost.

You can add more rules to the script to cover more apps that
may be hogging your CPU when you don't want them to. Just look
at the 'main' section (last few lines of the script) and add
more rules as needed. Each rule looks like this:

```
    # [max_cpu_secs] [max_cpu_pct] are optional parameters to terminate-hogs
    # if not specified, default values will be used
    process-list '<some pattern>' | terminate-hogs [max_cpu_secs] [max_cpu_pct]
```

For example, the Firefox rule which only kills one process tab is:

```
    process-list '[/]firefox -contentproc -childID.*tab$' | terminate-hogs
```

And for Chrome/Chromium it is:

```
    process-list '[/]chrom(e|ium) --type=(renderer|utility)' | terminate-hogs
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
The seems to be working for the usage in bash:

```
watch -n 1 "ps aux | grep firefox"

watch -n 0.1 "ps aux | grep firefox"

watch -n 1 "ps aux | grep firefox && free -m"
```

Press F5 in Tab and watch

**When i kill the tab now with the right tab, i get the message tab is crashed now**

In Firefox, **about:performance** is right.

But check also this in bash if i close or open and load a page tab:

```
$ pidof firefox

$ pidof firefox-esr
```

`$ pgrep firefox`  **get the main/parentid of one or "n" profiles**

`$ pgrep firefox-esr` **get the main/parentid of one or "n" profiles**

Get **parentid** and **childid**

```
$ ps aux | grep firefox

$ ps aux | grep firefox | grep tab
```

You see the **parentBuildID** and  something of the **child/tab**

It looks like that you can't kill the **child/tab** only the **parentBuildID**.

`ps -ef | grep firefox | wc -l`

Comment: Try: `ps aux | grep firefox | awk '{print $2, $11, $3}' | sort -k3rn`. Still missing the URL though.