# How can I determine which browser tab is the most network intensive?

Tags: networking, firefox, top

`top` not only shows '*firefox*' but also its individual tabs, each identified as '*Isolated Web Co*'.
So it is possible to find which tab is hogging the processor and kill it with `kill <PID>`.

Is there a network monitoring tool that gives the equivalent information?

`nethogs` only shows '*firefox*', but doesn't break it down by tab.

---

*Edit*:
Even if Firefox added this info to `about:networking`, killing a tab can be more useful than closing:  a closed tab is 'gone' (except '*Reopen Closed Tab*', or via history), but a killed tab remains in place and can be recovered with `F5` or `<ctrl>r`.

Comment: Check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220827/what-is-the-way-to-determine-which-tab-in-firefox-is-using-100-of-one-of-my-cpu

Comment: And this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484388/monitoring-cpu-of-tabs-in-firefox

Comment: And this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78689/fix-firefox-is-already-running-issue-in-linux

Comment: Check this command "pidof firefox" or "pidof firefox-esr" in bash

Comment: @MarcusMüller They're not asking for that — it's just a statement that something similar is already possible. Sounds like a sensible introduction. In context, "equivalent information" then becomes "which tab is hogging the bandwidth".

Comment: @Andreas ah, thanks! deleted my comment.

Answer (score 6):

This isn’t the goal of your question, but it could be useful to some: in Firefox, about:performance (enter that in the URL bar) will show you how much memory each tab is using, and give an idea of each tab’s performance impact (“energy impact”). You can close tabs from this view to get rid of the performance hogs.

Firefox doesn’t include per-tab network monitoring, outside of the developer tools; you can see how much data is transferred between your computer and individual remote hosts in about:networking#sockets. Using the developer tools, you can open a network tracer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>) which will show the network activity of the current tab.

As far as I can tell, it wouldn’t be possible for external monitoring tools to assign network activity to a specific tab in Firefox, because the sockets used by the various tabs are shared by all the threads in a given Firefox process. So even if a tool such as `nethogs` were changed to track network usage by thread, it wouldn’t show any useful information with a finer granularity than it does today.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen, lots of useful info there. From your final paragraph it would seem that per tab network usage could be provided _only_ by the browser. It's frustrating that `about:networking` shows so much info but not per tab.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
The seems to be working for the usage in bash:

```
watch -n 1 "ps aux | grep [f]irefox"

watch -n 0.1 "ps aux | grep [f]irefox"

watch -n 1 "ps aux | grep [f]irefox && free -m"

watch -n 0.1 "ps aux | grep /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox"

watch -n 0.1 "ps aux | grep /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox && free -m"

watch -d -n 0.1 "ps aux | grep [f]irefox"
```

Load a page and press F5 in the tab(again and again or hold the F5 button pressed) and watch

**When i kill the a tab with the right pid i get the message in the tab, that the tab is crashed now ^^**

In Firefox, **about:performance** is right.

But check also this in bash if i close or open and load a page tab:

```
$ pidof firefox

$ pidof firefox-esr
```

`$ pgrep firefox`  **get the main/parentid of one or "n" profiles**

`$ pgrep firefox-esr` **get the main/parentid of one or "n" profiles**

Get **parentid** and **childid**

```
$ ps aux | grep [f]irefox

$ ps aux | grep [f]irefox | grep tab
```

You see the **parentBuildID** and  something of the **child/tab**

It looks like that you can't close the **child/tab** only the **parentBuildID**, if you kill the **child/tab** the tab will **crash** but not close(but killed).

`ps -ef | grep [f]irefox | wc -l`

`ps -ef | grep [f]irefox | grep tab | wc -l`

Comment: `[]` around the "f" in `[f]irefox` is unnecessary. You probably meant `[Ff]irefox`. You can also use `grep -i firefox` to account for all case variants.

Comment: With [f] i don't get the last line with the grep command it self in the output right? @Vilinkameni diff: beetwen "ps aux | grep firefox" and "ps aux | grep [f]irefox" is the last output line.

Comment: It's a hack, I admit I didn't know about it. Instead, I know about the idiomatic `| grep -v grep`. When I think about it, how it works is that the command `grep [f]irefox` won't get matched because of the characters `[` and `]` in the second argument, and the pattern happens to match `firefox`, without the `[]`.